# Include Part number to figure numbering

Tags: macros, floats, captions, parts

I am trying to modify the way the page numbers are handled so that the part number is included as part of the figure number. So for example, as per the MWE, the figure produced should be called Figure B.1.1 rather than 1.1. This is controlled using the property : "\counterwithin{figure}{section}". I tried "\counterwithin{figure}{part}{section}" but no joy. The "\counterwithin{figure}{part}" command works, but then it loses the "section numbering" (i.e. Outputs B.1).

To sum up, I just need to output B.1.1.

Compile MWE under XeLaTeX.

[image: Output from MWE, figure label 1.1]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{extarticle}

% For forcing images to be placed where declared
\usepackage{float}
% To use custom font
\usepackage{fontspec}
% To modify sections/part/chapter etc. properties
\usepackage{titlesec}
% To modify caption properties
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
% To manipulate figure numbers
\usepackage{chngcntr}
% To include images
\usepackage{graphicx}
% To reset section numbers when a new part declared
\counterwithin*{section}{part}
% Remove hyphens from captions
\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}
% Do not hyphenate text
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
% Use colour names and be able to declare colours
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
% Change font to Arial
\setmainfont{Arial}
% Set my own colours
\definecolor{myBlue}{HTML}{005B82}
\definecolor{myLightBlue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{myCaptionBlue}{HTML}{1F497D}
% Change the way the Part headings look like
\titleformat{\part}[hang]{\color{myBlue}\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thepart}{1em}{}
% Part headings to use Alphabets rather than Roman Numerals
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}}
% Change the way the section heading looks like
\titleformat*{\section}{\color{myBlue}\bfseries\fontsize{14}{0}\selectfont}
% Change the way the subsection heading looks like
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\color{myBlue}\bfseries\fontsize{13}{0}\selectfont}
% Change the way the subsubsection heading looks like
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\color{myLightBlue}\bfseries\fontsize{11}{0}\selectfont}
% Add a custom subsubsubsection, and change the way the heading looks like for it
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}
    {-3.25ex \@plus-1ex \@minus-.2ex}
    {0.5ex \@plus .1ex}
    {\color{myLightBlue}\itshape\bfseries\fontsize{11}{0}\selectfont}
    }
\makeatother
\let\subsubsubsection\paragraph
% Change the way the caption looks like
\captionsetup{labelfont={color=myCaptionBlue,it},textfont={color=myCaptionBlue,it}}
% Ensure figure numbers include section numbers into account
\counterwithin{figure}{section}


\begin{document}

\part{First Part}

\section{Introduction}

Dummy Text

\part{Second Part}

\section{Image}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thepart-\arabic{figure}}` ???

Answer (score 1):

It is unusual, that sections numbering doesn't contain part number. How you than know that some section, for example with number 3 belong to part A or to part B?

In the case, that you are willing to change section numbering, than after `\titleformat*{\section}{\color{myBlue}\bfseries\fontsize{14}{0}\selectfont}` add `\counterwithin{section}{part}`:

[image]

In the case, that you persist to have your sistem of section numbering, than it is sufficient after `\counterwithin{figure}{section}` add `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thepart.\thesection.\arabic{figure}}`.

**Edit:**:
Complete MWE for this case is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{extarticle}

% For forcing images to be placed where declared
\usepackage{float}
% To use custom font
\usepackage{fontspec}
% To modify sections/part/chapter etc. properties
\usepackage{titlesec}
% To modify caption properties
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
% To manipulate figure numbers
\usepackage{chngcntr}
% To include images
\usepackage{graphicx}
% To reset section numbers when a new part declared
% Remove hyphens from captions
\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}
% Do not hyphenate text
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
% Use colour names and be able to declare colours
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
% Change font to Arial
\setmainfont{Arial}
% Set my own colours
\definecolor{myBlue}{HTML}{005B82}
\definecolor{myLightBlue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{myCaptionBlue}{HTML}{1F497D}
% Change the way the Part headings look like
\titleformat{\part}[hang]{\color{myBlue}\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thepart}{1em}{}
% Part headings to use Alphabets rather than Roman Numerals
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}}
% Change the way the section heading looks like
\titleformat*{\section}{\color{myBlue}\bfseries\fontsize{14}{0}\selectfont}
% Change the way the subsection heading looks like
\counterwithin{section}{part} % <-----
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\color{myBlue}\bfseries\fontsize{13}{0}\selectfont}
% Change the way the subsubsection heading looks like
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\color{myLightBlue}\bfseries\fontsize{11}{0}\selectfont}
% Add a custom subsubsubsection, and change the way the heading looks like for it
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}
    {-3.25ex \@plus-1ex \@minus-.2ex}
    {0.5ex \@plus .1ex}
    {\color{myLightBlue}\itshape\bfseries\fontsize{11}{0}\selectfont}
    }
\makeatother
\let\subsubsubsection\paragraph
% Change the way the caption looks like
\captionsetup{labelfont={color=myCaptionBlue,it},textfont={color=myCaptionBlue,it}}
% Ensure figure numbers include section numbers into account
\counterwithin{figure}{section}


\begin{document}
\part{First Part}

\section{Introduction}
Dummy Text

\part{Second Part}
\section{Image}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
some trext
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I can definitely see what I want in these examples. The reason I have this kind of numbering system, is because initially I was resetting the count every section i.e. Figure 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 for Section 1 and Figure 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3 for Section 2 and so on. However, I added Parts into the mix, which obviously broke the numbering. So I just needed the same numbering as before, but with a Part number in front i.e. A.1.1, A.1.2, A.1.3, A.2.1, A.2.2, A.2.3 -> And when next Part starts it would go B.1.1 and so on.

Comment: Agreed that it is a bit confusing to not have the Part letter in front of section numbers

Comment: So if I add \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thepart.\thesection.\arabic{section}} and add another figure after B.1.1, that figure is also labelled as B.1.1. It seems the \arabic{section} is the same as \thesection. \arabic{section} needs to be replaced with the figure counter... this gives me some hints to I will post here if I figure out the issue

Comment: @famakki1, no. it should be B.1.2. Now I see, that i have an error in answer. Instead of `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thepart.\thesection.\arabic{section}}` it should be `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thepart.\thesection.\arabic{figure}} `. Answer is now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

[image: xx]

Add to your preamble the  two  lines marked:

```
% To modify caption properties
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bf-part}{\textbf{\thepart.#2}} %<<<<<<<<<<added
\captionsetup{labelformat=bf-part,labelsep=endash} %<<<<<<<<<<added
```

and remove duplicate

```
% Remove hyphens from captions
\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}
```

It will be better to also remove

```
%% Change the way the caption looks like
\captionsetup{labelfont={color=myCaptionBlue,it},textfont={color=myCaptionBlue,it}}
```

and unify everything in one place

```
% To modify caption properties
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bf-part}{\textbf{\thepart.#2}} %<<<<<<<<<<added
\captionsetup{%
    labelformat=bf-part, %<<<<<<<<<<added
    labelsep=endash,
    labelfont={color=myCaptionBlue,it},
    textfont={color=myCaptionBlue,it,footnotesize}}
```

This is the complete code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{extarticle}

% For forcing images to be placed where declared
\usepackage{float}
% To use custom font
\usepackage{fontspec}
% To modify sections/part/chapter etc. properties
\usepackage{titlesec}
% To modify caption properties
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bf-part}{\textbf{\thepart.#2}} %<<<<<<<<<<added
\captionsetup{%
    labelformat=bf-part,
    labelsep=endash, %<<<<<<<<<<added
    labelfont={color=myCaptionBlue,it},
    textfont={color=myCaptionBlue,it,footnotesize}} 

% To manipulate figure numbers
\usepackage{chngcntr}
% To include images
\usepackage{graphicx}
% To reset section numbers when a new part declared
\counterwithin*{section}{part}
% Remove hyphens from captions
%\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}
% Do not hyphenate text
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
% Use colour names and be able to declare colours
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
% Change font to Arial
\setmainfont{Arial}
% Set my own colours
\definecolor{myBlue}{HTML}{005B82}
\definecolor{myLightBlue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{myCaptionBlue}{HTML}{1F497D}
% Change the way the Part headings look like
\titleformat{\part}[hang]{\color{myBlue}\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thepart}{1em}{}
% Part headings to use Alphabets rather than Roman Numerals
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}}
% Change the way the section heading looks like
\titleformat*{\section}{\color{myBlue}\bfseries\fontsize{14}{0}\selectfont}
% Change the way the subsection heading looks like
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\color{myBlue}\bfseries\fontsize{13}{0}\selectfont}
% Change the way the subsubsection heading looks like
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\color{myLightBlue}\bfseries\fontsize{11}{0}\selectfont}
% Add a custom subsubsubsection, and change the way the heading looks like for it
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}
    {-3.25ex \@plus-1ex \@minus-.2ex}
    {0.5ex \@plus .1ex}
    {\color{myLightBlue}\itshape\bfseries\fontsize{11}{0}\selectfont}
}
\makeatother
\let\subsubsubsection\paragraph
%%%% Change the way the caption looks like
%%\captionsetup{labelfont={color=myCaptionBlue,it},textfont={color=myCaptionBlue,it}}
% Ensure figure numbers include section numbers into account
\counterwithin{figure}{section} 
\begin{document}
    
    \part{First Part}
    
    \section{Introduction}      
        \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{fig:my_label}
    \end{figure}
    
    Dummy Text
    
    \part{Second Part}      
    \section{Image}     
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example-image-b}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{fig:my_label}
    \end{figure}
        
\end{document}
```